# Integrate Spring Boot application with remote Terracotta server / Ehcache

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache, terracotta

I found a lot of examples which show how to integrate an Ehcache in a Spring Boot application, e.g. [as described here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-ehcache). As far as I understand this example, the Ehcache itself is running in the Spring application.

Our setup, however, provides a Terracotta server acting as a "central" cache instance. Unforutnately I haven't found any documentation so far, how to tell my Spring Boot application to use that remote Terracotta server as Ehcache.

Do you have any examples or helpful information?

Answer (score 0):

Define tc-config xml as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <tc:tc-config xmlns:tc="http://www.terracotta.org/config"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    
      <tc-properties>
        <property name="l2.nha.dirtydb.autoDelete" value="true"/>
        <property name="l1.cachemanager.enabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="logging.maxLogFileSize" value="1024"/>
      </tc-properties>
    
    
      <servers>
        
        <server host="localhost" name="localhost:9090" bind="0.0.0.0">
          <data>c:/server-data</data>
          <logs>c:/server-logs</logs>
          <index>c:/server-index</index>
          <tsa-port>9090</tsa-port>
          <jmx-port>9091</jmx-port>
          <tsa-group-port>9092</tsa-group-port>
            <dataStorage size="1g">
              <offheap size="1g"/>
            </dataStorage>
        </server>
        
    
        <client-reconnect-window>120</client-reconnect-window>
    
      </servers>
      
      <clients>
        <logs>C:\logs</logs>
      </clients>
      
    </tc:tc-config>
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
  <artifactId>ehcache-terracotta</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
  <artifactId>terracotta-toolkit-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

ehcache.xml

```
<terracottaConfig url="${pathOftc-config}" rejoin="true" />
```